# Dynamically generate SQL column on runtime using Django Models

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to create a model based on current active members of a particular sports team of different state, I want to generate a `Member_Name` field based on the number of `Team_Members` field value. For example, if there are 3 active `Team_Members`, Django model should create 3 `Member_Name` Fields accordingly.

```
STATE_CHOICE = ['state1', 'state2', 'state3']
state = sorted(STATE_CHOICE)
SPORT_CHOICE = ['basketball', 'football', 'cricket', 'hockey']


class Sports(models.Model):
    state = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=state, default=state[0])
    team_members = models.IntegerField(required=True)
    sport = models.CharField(choice=SPORT_CHOICE, default=STATE_CHOICE[0])
```

Comment: This looks like bad modeling to me. Typically columns are *fixed*. What you probably want is a *many-to-many* field.

Comment: Furthermore you probably should rename your model. For example `Team` since this seems to deal with a team, not with a sport (and definitely not sports).

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a bad modeling, you should use many2many instead

```
class TeamMembers(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Sports(models.Model):
    state = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=state, default=state[0])
    team_members = models.ManyToManyField(TeamMembers)
    sport = models.CharField(choice=SPORT_CHOICE, default=STATE_CHOICE[0])
```

So that way each Sports can have Many TeamMembers, and Many TeamMembers have be a part of many Sports... if you need each member be a part of only one sport you can use `OneToManyField`

Checkout the Django Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Where a bit more about Many to Many relations: 
https://support.airtable.com/hc/en-us/articles/218734758-A-beginner-s-guide-to-many-to-many-relationships